# Why composer clone whole repo?

Tags: git, composer-php, bitbucket

I did config a bitbucket repository composer.json but composer is cloning whole repository and its branches with git folder.

how can I get just selected branch?

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "greenweb/framework",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://bitbucket.org/my_team/my_framework.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "origin/develop"
                },
                "version": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "greenweb/framework": "*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org/my_team/my_framework.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "greenweb/framework": "dev-develop"
    }
}
```

Then run:

```
$ composer install
```

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories.

Comment: in this way I get `Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` and I think this is related to ssh.

Comment: I change url with https one and I get `No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag`

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://burgiblog.com/2012/03/08/depending-on-packages-without-composer-json-in-composer-php-dependency-manager/